# In boost::posix_time, how to construct time_duration from volatile time_duration?

Tags: c++, boost, volatile

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
using boost::posix_time::time_duration;
int main()
{
  volatile time_duration t0;
  time_duration t1 = t0;
  return 0;
}
```

With this command:

```
g++ test01.cpp -std=c++11 -I /boost_1_55_0/ -o test01
```

And I get this error:

> test01.cpp:6:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::posix_time::time_duration::time_duration(volatile boost::posix_time::time_duration&)

I'm using gcc 4.8.2; any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by declaring it `volatile`?

Comment: Perhaps this is related to [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41518)?

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm using gcc version 4.8.2, while the bug yseems to be in gcc 4.3.

Comment: @e271p314: From that comment I can tell that you only read about 30% of the way down the page. _Read the **whole** bug history._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to [a GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41518). Workaround it like so:

```
volatile time_duration t0;
time_duration t1 = const_cast<time_duration&>(t0);
```

It works because `const_cast` can remove volatility as well as constness. I'm not sure how strictly safe this is, mind you.

An alternative fix is to get rid of the `volatile` in the first place; it very rarely serves any purpose nowadays.